# Inverse search wrong for colored text

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I am using large blocks of colored text in my latex documents. Unfortunately, the the inverse search (in TexShop at least) does not work correctly inside of them.
The coursor goes to the first line after the block of colored text.
For example, click on the 2nd line of the pdf output for the following example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue} 1\\
2\\
3\\
4} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: not related to the search probably but note `\color` only has one argument so that would make the whole document blue not just the part between `{` and `}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I corrected the code.